# Would it be possible to connect a keg (or series of kegs) to a soda fountain?

Tags: kegerator

Before I go converting my old refrigerator into a kegerator, I was wondering if there was a way to possible connect my keg(s) to a soda fountain? It may grate against the traditionalist tap handles, but I was just wondering about this before I go drilling into the fridge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean using a soda fountain to dispense your beer, my understanding is that the taps on a soda fountailn aren't set up roght for serving beer.

Comment: All I can really tell you is that I know of someone who tried it and it didn't work well for him.  No personal experience to relate.

Answer (score 1):

You can use old, reconditioned Pepsi and Coke kegs (ball-lock and pin-lock respectively) for beer.

All you need to dispense beer from these types of keg is: the Keg, CO2, tubing from CO2 to Keg for pressurization, tubing from Keg to spigot/tap/or whatever to your cup.

While a traditional setup for the soda machine would not work I would assume that if you had the CO2 hookup for the kegs you wanted to use, and then re routed the singe tubing for the beer to the spigots on the soda machine it should work. You just wouldn't have the carbonated soda coming out the same time as the syrup.  It would be pre-conditioned in the keg and come out already carbonated from the spout.

Answer (score 1):

The soda fountain mixes syrup and soda water, a beer tap strictly dispenses beer.

If you were able to get the fountain to flow without adding water, and could properly control the pressure of the beer being dispensed I suppose it could work.

The small syrup channels would probably cause you to use too much pressure for a good flow rate, which may cause really foamy beer (or a very, very slow pour).